# ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE создание файла

Tags: java, android, uri

Запускаю `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` с флагами для получения доступа на запись и чтение каталога:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
 intent.setType("*/*");  
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION  
                 | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION 
                 | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);  
 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_FOLDER_ACCESS);
```

В `onActivityResult()` ловлю так:

```
 ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
 Uri uriFolder = intent.getData();
 int takeFlags = data.getFlags() & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION           | 
                          Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);       
 cr.takePersistableUriPermission(uriFolder, takeFlags);
```

В итоге получаю разрешение на чтение и запись к каталогу `uriFolder`, далее пытаюсь записать в этот каталог файл:

```
 Uri uriFile = Uri.withAppendedPath(uriFolder, "filename.txt");
 OutputStream os = cr.openOutputStream(uriFile, "w");
```

И при открытии потока на запись нарываюсь на `IllegalArgumentException`, который показывает на `MalformedUri`

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Говорят что удобнее это делать с [`DocumentFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile), ну или можно подсмотреть его реализацию...  Примерчик с `DocumentFile` есть в ответе: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26765884

Comment: Да, это решение - оформите его как ответ

Comment: Лучше вы - на живом, проверенном примере, потому что я ещё с этим не работал.

Comment: ok, проверю чуть позже

Comment: @woess проверил, да работает - файл создается. Есть небольшие шероховатости с именованием файла, тем не менее схема рабочая.